# .Net core 3.1 + GraphQL ==> "error": "Unexpected end of JSON input"

Tags: graphql, .net-core-3.1, graphql-playground

I developed a .net core 3.1 web API and I've added **GraphQL** and **PlayGround** to it. When I try to start the Playground I encountered this error that bored me. I googled too many times and I have read many articles and forums about it and I've tried their suggested ways but still, the problem exists. Also, I should say I haven't this problem with .net core 2.2.

I decided to simplify my solution and remove the extra foliage of my project and upload it to you that you can help me.
The simplified version of that project I'm currently working on it is available [here on google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fJvLoH8wKPeLNul9luPHSXNu8-mbwaEz/view?usp=sharing).

Also, I found a solution with .net core 3.1 that hasn't this problem but still, I can't find my mistake(s). I've uploaded this correct solution [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ru4hXhf9ztTdmw7ZmbvwIWs1rCV6zK8x/view?usp=sharing).

In this simplified version I didn't connect to the database and didn't add any related of its packages to the project. I'm returning in-memory data in this simplified version instead of contacting the database.

This is the picture of the error that I'm facing:
[image]

And The **.csproj** file of the simplified project is like below:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>NetCore3._1GraphQL</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="graphiql" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL" Version="3.0.0-preview-1352" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Ui.Playground" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="RandomNameGeneratorLibrary" Version="1.2.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the simplified and erroneous project, afaict, it is configured with a routing which maps `/graphql` endpoint to a controller but does not contain a matching controller. So, the server returns 404 response and graphql playground produces error message. Adding a controller (or a middleware) made it work.

Below are the changes to the simplified and erroneous project that made it work:

1. Add an api controller matching `/graphql` routing.

```cs
// GraphqlController.cs
// using statements are omitted
namespace NetCore3._1GraphQL.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class GraphqlController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _provider; 
        private readonly IDocumentExecuter _executer;
        private readonly IDataLoaderContextAccessor _loader;

        public GraphqlController(
            IDocumentExecuter executer,
            IServiceProvider provider, 
            IDataLoaderContextAccessor loader)
        {
            _executer = executer;
            _provider = provider;
            _loader = loader;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] GraphQLRequest graphQLRequest)
        {
            if (graphQLRequest == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(graphQLRequest));
            }

            var _query = graphQLRequest.Query;
            var _inputs = graphQLRequest.Variables?.ToObject<Inputs>();
            var _options = new ExecutionOptions
            {
                Schema = new GraphQLSchema(_provider)
                {
                    Query = new GraphQLQuery(_loader),
                },
                Query = _query,
                Inputs = _inputs,
                FieldNameConverter = new PascalCaseFieldNameConverter()
            };

            try
            {
                var result = await _executer.ExecuteAsync(_options).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (result.Errors?.Count > 0)
                {
                    return BadRequest(result);
                }

                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. Uncomment the line `public JObject Variables { get; set; }` in `BaseGraphQLQuery.cs`.
3. `BaseGraphQLQuery` class is an implementation of a GraphQL request, not a GraphQL query. Rename it as `GraphQLRequest` or change the parameter name in the controller's post action to `BaseGraphQLQuery`.

[image: A successfull query with Graphql Playground app.]

Comment: Thank you @moustapha. I am very busy right now, but I will check your answer as soon as possible.

Comment: I checked your answer and you were right. A year ago, when I downloaded this project from the Internet, I was a beginner in GraphQL and did not know that there must be a controller to handle GraphQL requests.

But let's add this point to your answer to make it better for other readers of this question.

Change line 76 where the app used the GraphQLPlayground tool like this:

`app.UseGraphQLPlayground(options: new GraphQLPlaygroundOptions() { Path = "/graphqlplayground", GraphQLEndPoint = "/graphql" });`

and the PlayGround will appear at this https://localhost:44313/graphqlplayground

Comment: Do you have a working .net core controller app which is using Graphql.net 4?

Comment: @killjoy, sorry, I don't have one at the moment. Please have a look at the [graphql-dotnet examples](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/examples). If you have an issue please provide the details so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

add in the startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //add this
        services.AddSingleton<MyAppSchema>();
    }
```